# Get selected Features in LayerView

Tags: javascript, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, arcgis-experience-builder

I am currently developing 2 widgets in the Experience Builder.
In one of the two widgets I have implemented the Esri search widget and mark the feature in the LayerView via the search result. Now I would like to use the other widget to react when a feature layer is selected and then read it.

Is this somehow possible I have already looked in the Map, View, Layer, LayerView to see if it is possible to read the currently selected features but so far I have not found anything.

The whole thing I had already managed via the popup but I would like to deactivate the popup.